# In orient-db how can i round up a decimal value

Tags: orientdb

In orientdb i have a sample query of my problem

```
select  eval('((23 + 46) *  1.0 ) / 2') as abc from SomeClass
```

above query returns 34.5 I want to round it up to 35. I applied asInteger() but it didn't work.

```
select  eval('((23 + 46) *  1.0 ) / 2').asInteger() as abc from SomeClass
```

above query returns 34 but i want it to be 35

Comment: when you add 0.5 and call .asInteger() then also you can do sort of a round up thingy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if there are some native functions to achieve that.

But you could create a javascript function with Studio called for example ceil

and in the body do the work.

try to insert this function.

```
insert into OFunction set name = 'ceil', language = 'javascript', code = 'return Math.ceil(num);', parameters = ["num"]
```

and then

```
select  ceil(eval('((23 + 46) *  1.0 ) / 2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this function is not available out of the box, you could define your own Function (open Studio -> Functions tab) with name "round" that gets 1 parameter "value" with this code:

```
return java.lang.Math.round(value);
```

Then you can call it from SQL with:

```
select round(value) as abc from SomeClass
```

Where value is the property in class SomeClass.